# External Dupont male connector

Tags: atmel

I would like to program my board without opening the enclosure.
On the PCB I have a standard 2x3 Dupont male connector that I use with the Atmel ICE programmer. I am looking for a similar connector to be mounted externally but I did not find anything useful. Do such connector exist or can you suggest another solution?

Edit: this is the Dupont connector used by my HP 48G calculator. I was thinking of something similar. [image: HP 48G connector]

Comment: @Dave Why your downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the "DuPont" style pin headers are not meant for external connections.

Pick any other connector you like — perhaps the ubiquitous DE-9 or RJ-45.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the advice. I think I'll try with a 6 pins mini din.